# Scrapy + Python, returning multiple items, issue reading page

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to extract multiple items to a database using Scrapy with python.
To build my code I used the Scrapy shell to read the page first and test the lines of code related to the data extraction.

```
scrapy shell "http://www.goodmans.net/d/1706/brands.htm"
```

I tried the following function and got the result I wanted (extracting all brands)

```
response.css('.SubDepartments a::text').extract()
```

[image: The result was what I expected]

Then I built the code, run it with `scrapy crawl goodmans` and it gave me an error:

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
class GoodmanSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "goodmans" 
    start_urls = ['http://www.goodmans.net/d/1706/brands.htm']

    def parse(self, response):
        category = response.css('.SubDepartments a::text').extract() 
        category_url = response.css('.SubDepartments a::attr(href)').extract()
        yield {'Category': category, 'url': categoy_url}
```

[image: This was the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting part of the error is not visible in your screenshot. The last line says:

```
... line 10, in parse
       yield {'Category': category, 'url': categoy_url}
    NameError: name 'categoy_url' is not defined
```

So, a simple misspelling :)

Comment: OMG :O  I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!